# Select distinct didn't work correctly (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a query like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.name AS role, r.id AS role_id, u.id AS user_id, concat( u.firstname, '', u.lastname ) AS name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN members m ON u.id = m.user_id
INNER JOIN member_roles mr ON m.id = mr.member_id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = mr.role_id
WHERE m.project_id =11
```

My goal is to get unique `u.id`(user_id). Unfortunately, the result show two duplicate `u.id` from this multiple join. If I remove the last one join(`INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = mr.role_id`), this query run correctly. But I didn't know why it was wrong if I add this line to my query. The last one `join` line is necessary to get the role's name, so I can ignore it. Can someone tell me where I did incorrectly in my query?

Comment: the whole SETof values returned is unique, not just the first one

Comment: Give us sample data and expected result through sqlfiddle.

Comment: If a user has multiple roles, what do you want the query to return?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, if a user has multiple roles, then the query should return the highest priority of role. Ex: admin, leader, developer will should return admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` in your query to get rows with unique `user_id`.

Then the updated query will be look like the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.name AS role, r.id AS role_id, u.id AS user_id, 
concat( u.firstname, '', u.lastname ) AS name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN members m ON u.id = m.user_id
INNER JOIN member_roles mr ON m.id = mr.member_id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = mr.role_id
WHERE m.project_id =11 GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that users can have multiple roles on a project.  Fortunately, MySQL has `group_concat()` which can bring the multiple values together:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, concat( u.firstname, '', u.lastname ) AS name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(r.name) as roles,
       GROUP_CONCAT(r.id) as role_ids
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     members m
     ON u.id = m.user_id INNER JOIN
     member_roles mr ON m.id = mr.member_id INNER JOIN
     roles r
     ON r.id = mr.role_id
WHERE m.project_id = 11
GROUP BY u.id;
```